# Using two dynamic layers on Google fusion maps

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have created several Fusion table maps, which all work great, but in one of the maps, I want to create a dual layer functionality, so my POLYGON is viewed from the beginning, and when you zoom in, you instead have the functionality of LINESTRINGS. From what I understood, it's not possible to have two active dual layers simultaneously, and having functioning lightboxes for them.

How can I make something like this work?

Here is the example: [Parkeringszoner i København](http://parkingspot.dk/parkeringszoner-i-kobenhavn/)

Comment: What is your question?  You can have multiple (up to 5) FusionTablesLayers on a single map.  You can only apply dynamic _styles_ (from javascript) to one of those, but you use queries on all of them.

Comment: Look at using [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

You can have multiple (up to 5) FusionTablesLayers on a single map and write code to change the one being displayed based on the zoom level of the map.